# Anyway to escape ODEintWarning (scipy)?

Tags: python, ode, numerics

I am trying to fit a differential equation to some data and obtain the parameters of the underlying model. This requires me to try out various parameter values, but this often gives me an ODEintWarning. Having a few of these warnings is OK, but having too many will cause my program to crash quite often (I work using Spyder and if I click somewhere on the GUI while the program is running, Spyder will freeze).

Is there a way to detect an ODEintWarning and escape it? In pseudocode, I essentially want something like:

```
for parameter in parameters_list:
    try:
        x = odeint(dxdt, x0,t, *parameters)
    except (at the first sign of an) ODEintWarning:
        pass (and go on to the next set of parameters to be tested)
```

Or, is my best option to detect bad parameter values in advance and try not to feed them into ODEint in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried if switching to `solve_ivp` with method `LSODA` gives similar enough results with more useful warning/error behavior? // Did you read the documentation to find and apply the `mxhnil`, if it does what the doc line appears to say?

Comment: Usually you get warning messages when the solution diverges. You could try to avoid that by modifying the ODE function to be sub-linear outside the region of interest where the adapted solution is expected to lie. // In a related but different domain, BVP solvers ameliorate this kind of problem by following a multiple-shooting approach

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I haven't tried ```solve_ivp``` and will try it out. (I might also try RK45 as I want a faster screening method) I haven't changed ```mxhnil```, because I don't mind odeint printing messages. As far as I understand, the problem is that odeint can't find good timesteps, and I want it to give up if it can't, instead of trying endlessly.

Comment: That's why keeping it sub-linear is important. In the most simple case, divide the derivatives vector, after it is constructed, by a suitable power of `max(1,norm(x)/R)`, where `R` is chosen so that the solution is inside `norm(x)<R` with a wide margin.

Comment: Stackoverflow would be a good place for this question, ignoring any of the science-related stuff.

Comment: Thanks Lutz and Spencer. I tried out `solve_ivp` and it seems to work, although I need to tinker with the `terminal` condition to get it to work properly. In any case though, I realized that checking the eigen values of the ODE before integration to screen whether the solution y(t) will diverge to infinity or not is probably fastest.